# Pass a param from pug to JSX

Tags: node.js, express, pug, reactjs

I'm building a game using Express and React. I need to access the userId in my `index.jsx` file to perform actions on my controllers, like increment the user score.

My route renders an `index.pug` file while passing a `user_id` param:

```
//server.js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  const userId = req.query.userId
  res.render('index', {userId: userId})
})
```

Then I can access the `userId` in my pug file, like this:

```
// index.pug
body
  div#errors
  #root
  p #{userId} // prints the User Id
```

Now I need to access this `userId` param in my `index.jsx` file that contains the React Components.

```
class Cell extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <button onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
          {userId}
        </button>
      )
    } 
  }
```

But that doesn't work, as I expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do using `window` object

Let's say in your `.pug` file

```
script.
   var userId = '#{userId}'; //assigning pug value to window object.
```

Now you can access `userId` in `react` component as `window.userId`

```
class Cell extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <button onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
          {window.userId}
        </button>
      )
    } 
  }
```

Comment: I did this the same way using `window` object to pass `pug` data to `react` component

Comment: Thanks! That's the way indeed. Here's how I implemented it:
```index.pug
   script.
      window.fbId = !{JSON.stringify(userId)};
```
Then in index.jsx:
```ReactDOM.render(
  <Game userId={userId} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)```

Comment: Oh you passed to `render` function. That's also fine.