# Pass a variable containing a function from pug to react component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, pug

QUESTION

**How can I pass a variable containing a function from a pug file (I don't think it's specific to .pug files) to a react component?**

---

**route.js**

```
const login = () => { ... 'log the user in here' ... };

app.get('/test', (req,res) => {
  res.render('page.pug', {varName: {list_test: ['hello', 'goodye'], login_func: login}});
```

**page.pug**

```
body
  script.
    var data = !{JSON.stringify(varName)}
```

**file.jsx**

```
// Imagine this being called from a react component's constructor
console.log(data);
```

> (file.jsx) Console output: {list_test: ['hello, 'goodye']}

*Notice that the function 'login' (as well as its associated key 'login_func') has disappeared from the variable?!*

---

The answers to the linked questions outlined below doesn't work when the variable contains functions, however it does work for strings, numbers, lists, and objects. Therefore, this is not a duplicate of any of the following:

[Pass a param from pug to JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41416236/10238810)

[Passing a variable from a jade file to a React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31397809/10238810)

---

**It kinda makes sense** (Me considering what the issue might be - I might be wrong)

When you stringify the JSON object, I suppose it would be troublesome to turn a string into a function:

`function sayHello() { console.log('Hello') }`

`var string = "sayHello"`

Now to somehow turn that string into a non string again and point to the sayHello function would cause problems - is what I think.

Comment: short answer: you can't. think about the context where the function is written and executed. pug is on some server somewhere and react is running on a browser on  someones laptop. this is why HTTP requests  exist

Comment: @azium Can you think of any work around? I have to somehow make this work. Wait... I am so stupid. I am litterly passing variables from a .js file to the pug file. So why don't I just import that .js file in my react file so I can access it from the component instead?!?! I AM SO STUPID!

Comment: it's not a workaround.. create an endpoint on the server that executes that function then make an HTTP request from your client code using `fetch` or whatever http library you like (`axios` for example)

Answer (score 1):

> **Use environmental variables**
>
> pug -> environment variable -> react

The Create React App build allows for environment variables to be used within the app. To add an environment variable create a .env file in the root of your project, then add the appropriate variables and prefix the variable name with REACT_APP_. For example:

REACT_APP_MYVAR = "someString"
In the app these variables can be accessed within your components with {process.env.REACT_APP_MYVAR}, or within the HTML with %REACT_APP_MYVAR%.

So in order to send pass a variable from pug to react all you would have to do would simply be to first pass your variable to the environment variable and then have your react file access that environment variable.